# How to change direction of a sheet that is build by Open XML

Tags: java, c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to change direction of XLSX file that is generated by the bellow code.

In excel software we can do this like:
[image]

MSDN says we can do this by [Alignment.ReadingOrder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.alignment.readingorder(v=office.14).aspx) but how i use it?

The following code get a set of data and make an excel file.

```
public class ExcelHelper
{
    public class ExcelData
    {
        public string SheetName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public static byte[] GenerateExcel(ExcelData data)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
        var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();

        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        var sheetData = new SheetData();

        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

        var sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        var sheet = new Sheet()
        {
            Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            SheetId = 1,
            Name = data.SheetName ?? "Sheet 1",
        };

        sheets.AppendChild(sheet);

        //--------------------------------

        UInt32 rowIndex = 0;

        //-------------------------------- header

        var rowHeader = new Row { RowIndex = ++rowIndex };

        foreach (var header in data.Headers)
        {
            var cell = new Cell
            {
                DataType = CellValues.InlineString,
                //CellReference = header + rowIndex
            };

            var inlineString = new InlineString();
            var text = new Text { Text = header ?? string.Empty };

            inlineString.AppendChild(text);
            cell.AppendChild(inlineString);

            rowHeader.AppendChild(cell);
        }

        sheetData.AppendChild(rowHeader);

        //-------------------------------- data

        foreach (var row in data.Rows)
        {
            var rowData = new Row { RowIndex = ++rowIndex };

            foreach (var cellData in row)
            {
                var cell = new Cell
                {
                    DataType = CellValues.InlineString,
                    //CellReference = cellData + rowIndex
                };

                var inlineString = new InlineString();
                var text = new Text { Text = cellData ?? string.Empty };

                inlineString.AppendChild(text);
                cell.AppendChild(inlineString);

                rowData.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(rowData);
        }

        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();

        var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        memoryStream.Dispose();

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by a trick ;)

Best practice is to create a template file by hand in MS Office Excel then open it by code and fill the target cells with the correct data.

```
public class ExcelHelper
{
    public static MemoryStream TemplateFile { get; set; }
    public static MemoryStream TemplateFileEn { get; set; }

    private static string[] ColumnsNames = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

    //todo: change
    private const string TemplateFilePath =
        @"\App_Data\TemplateFiles\Fax-ArchiveReport.xlsx";
    private const string TemplateFileEnPath =
        @"\App_Data\TemplateFiles\Fax-ArchiveReport-en.xlsx";

    public class ExcelData
    {
        public string SheetName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Headers { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> Rows { get; set; }
        public bool IsEn { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public static byte[] GenerateExcelV2(ExcelData data)
    {
        try
        {
            var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");

            using( MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream() )
            {
            if (data.IsEn)
            {
                if (TemplateFileEn == null)
                {
                    TemplateFileEn = new MemoryStream();

                    using (var stream = File.Open(root + TemplateFileEnPath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(TemplateFileEn);
                    }

                }

                TemplateFileEn.Position = 0;
                TemplateFileEn.CopyTo(file);
            }
            else
            {
                if (TemplateFile == null)
                {
                    TemplateFile = new MemoryStream();

                    using (var stream = File.Open(root + TemplateFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(TemplateFile);
                    }
                }

                TemplateFile.Position = 0;
                TemplateFile.CopyTo(file);
            }

            var result = UpdateCells(file, data.Title, data.Headers, data.Rows);

            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //todo: log in db
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] UpdateCells(MemoryStream doc, string title, List<string> headers, List<List<string>> rows)
    {
        // Open the document for editing.
        SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(doc, true);
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, "Fax-ArchiveReport");

        if (worksheetPart != null)
        {

            //----------------------------------------------- title

            Cell cellTitle = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, ColumnsNames[0], 2);
            var inlineStringTitle = new InlineString();

            inlineStringTitle.AppendChild(new Text { Text = title ?? string.Empty });
            cellTitle.AppendChild(inlineStringTitle);
            cellTitle.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.InlineString);

            //----------------------------------------------- data

            uint rowIndex = 4;
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                uint rowCellIndex = 0;
                foreach (var rowCell in row)
                {
                    Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, ColumnsNames[rowCellIndex], rowIndex);
                    var inlineStringRowCell = new InlineString();

                    inlineStringRowCell.AppendChild(new Text { Text = rowCell ?? string.Empty });
                    cell.AppendChild(inlineStringRowCell);
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.InlineString);

                    rowCellIndex++;
                }

                rowIndex++;
            }

            //-----------------------------------------------

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            spreadSheet.Close();

            var bytes = doc.ToArray();

            doc.Dispose();

            return bytes;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPartByName(SpreadsheetDocument document, string sheetName)
    {
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);

        if (sheets.Count() == 0)
        {
            // The specified worksheet does not exist.

            return null;
        }

        string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

        return worksheetPart;
    }

    // Given a worksheet, a column name, and a row index, 
    // gets the cell at the specified column and 
    private static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet, string columnName, uint rowIndex)
    {
        Row row = GetRow(worksheet, rowIndex);

        if (row == null)
            return null;

        return
            row.Elements<Cell>()
                .Where(c => string.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, columnName + rowIndex, true) == 0)
                .First();
    }

    // Given a worksheet and a row index, return the row.
    private static Row GetRow(Worksheet worksheet, uint rowIndex)
    {
        return worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().
          Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
    }
}
```